# Hypothesis test for ranked data

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, inference

I have a list of rankings in the following format:

```
  Item  | Score | Rank
  item1 |  0.97 | 6
  item2 |  0.53 | 4
  item3 |  0.05 | 1
  item4 |  0.68 | 5
  item5 |  0.10 | 2
  item6 |  0.29 | 3
```

I want to determine whether the difference between each two pair of ranked items is significant given the scores. What statistical test should I conduct? Thank you!

Comment: The way your question is worded, it's not amenable to a stats test. You want to compare each pair of items? e.g. You want to compare `item1` (rank = 6) with `item2` (rank = 4)? A simple answer is that they differ by two ranks. What null hypothesis do you want to test?

Comment: @RGregStacey: I have added the scores based on which the rankings are inferred. I want to determine whether the difference between each two pair of items is significant given the scores.

Comment: There might be tests appropriate for comparing two numbers (e.g. .97 vs .53), but I don't know of any. Most stats tests compare *distributions* of numbers. Why do you need significance here? You can see immediately that item1 and item2 differ by 0.97-0.53 = 0.44. I'm guessing you want to know which items differ *enough to be interesting*?

Comment: You could help us guide you toward the appropriate analysis if you tell us what you'd like to understand about your data. Do you want to know which items are the most different? Do you want to know if the differences can't be explained by chance? Something else?

Comment: @RGregStacey For two items ranked at position m and m+1 if the difference of their scores is not significant, then their relative positions do not matter.

Comment: How were the scores generated? What data was used?

Comment: I'm asking because calculating something like a p-value requires knowing something like the variance of each score. If the data is suitable for bootstrapping, that could be a way to calculate how variable a score is, and therefore calculate how meaningful the rankings are. When you let me know about the data I'll write an answer that explains how to do that in detail.